# how to configure spring dataflow for spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have spring batch project I want to configure it on spring cloud dataflow I m able to register it on SCDF but on launching task my job is not running
following is my configuration file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTask
public class BatchApplication {
/*@Autowired
BatchCommandLineRunner batchcommdrunner;

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
    System.out.println("Executed at :" +  new SimpleDateFormat().format(new Date()));
    return batchcommdrunner ;
}*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

And this is my batch confriguration file

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguaration {

@Autowired
private DataSource datasouce;

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public Environment env;

@Bean(name = "reader")
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Schedules> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[scheduleRecs]}") List<Schedules> scherecs) {
    ItemReader<Schedules> reader = new IteratorItemReader<Schedules>(scherecs);
    return reader;
}

@Bean(name = "CWSreader")
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Contents> CWSreader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[scheduleRecs]}") List<Contents> scherecs) {
    ItemReader<Contents> reader = new IteratorItemReader<Contents>(scherecs);
    return reader;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Bean
@StepScope
public BatchProcessor processor() {
    return new BatchProcessor();
}

@Bean(name = "batchSchedulePreparedStatement")
@StepScope
public BatchSchedulePreparedStatement batchSchedulePreparedStatement() {
    return new BatchSchedulePreparedStatement();
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Bean(name = "batchWriter")
@StepScope
public BatchWriter batchWriter() {
    BatchWriter batchWriter = new BatchWriter();
    batchWriter.setDataSource(datasouce);
    batchWriter.setSql(env.getProperty("batch.insert.schedule.query"));
    batchWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(batchSchedulePreparedStatement());
    return batchWriter;

}


@Bean("acheronDbTm")
@Qualifier("acheronDbTm")
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public JobExplorer jobExplorer() throws Exception {
    MapJobExplorerFactoryBean explorerFactoryBean = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean();
    explorerFactoryBean.setRepositoryFactory(mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean());
    explorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return explorerFactoryBean.getObject();
}

@Bean
public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean() {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager());
    return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean().getObject();
}

@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Bean(name = "batchPartition")
@StepScope
public BatchPartition batchPartition() {
    BatchPartition batchPartition = new BatchPartition();
    return batchPartition;
}



@Bean(name="taskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    poolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    poolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    poolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(35);
    poolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Acheron");
    poolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return poolTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean(name = "masterStep")
public Step masterStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner(slave()).partitioner("slave", batchPartition())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).build();
}


@Bean(name = "slave")
public Step slave() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("slave").chunk(100).faultTolerant().retryLimit(2)
            .retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class).reader(reader(null)).processor(processor())
            .writer(batchWriter()).build();

}


@Bean(name = "manageStagingScheduleMaster")
public Job manageStagingScheduleMaster(final Step masterStep) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("manageStagingScheduleMaster").preventRestart().incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(masterStep).build();
}
```

can anyone help me to configure it properly or is there any other way where I can monitor my batch jobs
I also tried with Spring boot admin but it is not supporting java configuration in SBA is there any way to add jobs without jobs in xml

I am launcing this job from controller

```
JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    System.out.println("Job Builder " + builder);
    JobParameters jobParameters = builder.toJobParameters();
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    return execution.getStatus().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/batch-job) shows a basic Spring batch application that can be launched as a task in Spring Cloud Data Flow.

Comment: I tried with that example but it is not working with my job configuration class

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's not working in your case? Do you have any information (such as stacktrace or failure)  to share?